# EmberJs - IE8 not firing selectionBinding update

Tags: ember.js

The following code works fine in chrome i have an observable property in the controller

```
{{view Ember.Select prompt="--ANY--" 
selectionBinding="GWVideoApp.VideosController.category" 
contentBinding="GWVideoApp.TagsController.categories" 
optionLabelPath="content.title" 
optionValuePath="content.title"}}
```

Controller:

```
category: {},
categoryDidChange: function() { this.recalcTags(); }.observes('category'),
```

But it seems like the update isn't happening for IE8

Comment: I'd definitely try upgrading jQuery as @rBull has suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same problem with Ember.Checkbox valueBinding.
Upgrading of jQuery from 1.6.4 to 1.7.2 has fixed this problem